# PHP, MySQL + PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: php, mysql, phonegap, cordova

Здравствуйте
Объясните, пожалуйста, принцип использования PHP и соответственно MySQL в приложении написанном на PhoneGap

Comment: Эм.. А каким боком там вообще php? o_O

Comment: Таким, что на одних html и js далеко не уедешь. В инете много примеров подобного использования (взять хотя бы этот https://codesundar.com/lesson/phonegap-php-mysql-example/), но до конца разобраться в них не могу.

Comment: Ну MySQL-то нормально, наверное, но вот тащить php на телефон...

Comment: Так, посмотрел ссылку - там речь идёт о том, что у тебя где-то (на твоём сервере) есть сервер на php, а приложение (которое на телефоне) просто к нему обращается.